# Is there a way to change an html line instead of rerendering the whole component?

Tags: reactjs, render

I am new to react and was wondering if there was a way to change one html line every second in the render method for example instead of rerendering the whole component?

I have to make a status bar where the time is displayed, so the date needs to be updated every second. Is it possible to only change the Menubar-time div?

```
    componentDidMount: function() {
        const self = this;
        self.interval = setInterval(function() {
            self.setState({
                now: new Date(),
            });
        }, 1000);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Menubar">
                <div className="Menubar-name">
                    <p>{this.state.login}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Menubar-date">
                    <p><Time value={this.state.now} format="DD/MM/YYYY" /></p>
                </div>
                <div className="Menubar-time">
                    <p><Time value={this.state.now} format="HH:mm:ss" /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: what about wrapping part of html that should be changed frequently into smaller component?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry about it - this seems like an unnecessary "optimisation" to me.

Comment: @wolendrahn: Wouldn't that be allmost the same? Might be a good idea tho. :)

Comment: @Tom Fenech:The thing is that it is for a webapp that should be live for several hours, so I believe that loading the date every second for five hours isn't really the best :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the whole component is not re-rendered. `render()` returns instance of virtual DOM and only difference between current DOM and new DOM(returned by a `render()`) is applied. So you do not need to worry about performance in this case.

When you feel your performance being poor, you may consider implementing [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). As for me, I had to implement this just once or twice. React itself needs optimizations in quite rare cases.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

React re-renders the whole tree when state changes but after that rendering it calculates the diff between the virtual dom and the dom and in the dom only the difference is re-rendered.
So basically you don't need to do anything React will take care that in the dom only the timer text will change.

isn't it awesome :p